# batch scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file

Intro : 
I am new to batch scripting. Will like to have a leads on the following scripts.

Objective : Have to write a batch command to update an application . And then read the log that is generated after the application has been updated , to check if it has been successfull.

I run the application using a  simple batch file , which has the command

`"C:\Program Files\Application\Test.exe" /application paramater /q /from "\\share\file"`

The logfile (xyz.log) for the result in generated in

`C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\locals~1\temp\Application`

I want my batch file to run the first command and read the results generated in the log file (serach for success string).

CanI get any inputs on this please.

Comment: In the interest of keeping to the methodology of this website, if your question has been answered, please accept an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ***NOT*** tested, but it's good starting point, and you can use it to learn some MS-DOS/batch commands. If you need specific syntax help, type in the command prompt `[some-command] /?`

```
@echo off
:: variables --------------------
set appexe=C:\Program Files\Application\Test.exe
set share=\\share\file
set logfile=%TEMP%\Application\xyz.log
set appcmd="%appexe%" /param /q /from "%share%"

if not exist "%appexe%" echo Executable not found& goto END
if not exist "%share%" echo Shared folder not found& goto END

:: run executable ---------------
%appcmd%

if not exist "%logfile%" echo Logfile not found& goto END

:: iterate through logfile ------
find "update success text" "%logfile%" >NUL || (echo Update unsuccessful& goto END)
echo Update successful!

:END
pause
exit
```

Edit: Used `find` rather than a for loop. +1 and thanks to Andriy M

Comment: Thankyou very much kevlar1818 and  Andriy M for your help in this.

Comment: The log file has multiple entries , some from the older date. This method suggested , looks for a string , but that string could necessarily be of an older date. How do i look for the latest "Update Sucessfull" string?? WHich is at the bottom most row of the log file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FIND` command to search a file for a string:

```
FIND "success" "%TEMP%\Application\xyz.log" >NUL && (ECHO Update successful) || (ECHO Update failed)
```

- `%TEMP%` evaluates to the system temporary folder for the current user.
- `>NUL` suppresses the output of the `FIND` command.
- `&&` passes control to the subsequent command (`ECHO`) if the string was found.
- `||` passes control to the command after it (the other `ECHO`) if the search failed.

If you want to perform more than one command as a result of `FIND`, you can use something like this:

```
FIND "string" file_name && (command1 & command2 & …) || (command3 & command4 & …)
```

Alternatively you can use the `GOTO` command. For example, like this:

```
FIND "success" "%TEMP%\Application\xyz.log" >NUL || (GOTO searchfailed)
series of commands as a result of successful search
GOTO :EOF

:searchfailed
series of commands as a result of unsuccessful search
```

`:label_name` is a label declaration. `GOTO searchfailed` means jump to the line where the `searchfailed` label is declared.

`GOTO :EOF` essentilly exits the batch script. (`:EOF` is a special pre-defined label that points at the **E**nd **O**f **F**ile.)